# Generate Token on postPersist with FOSOAuthServerBundle

Tags: php, api, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm trying to create a token on registration.
I use `FosUserBundle` as authenticator and `FOSOAuthServerBundle` for API.

Everything works well when i generate a token manually. But i want to generate it automatically after a successful registration. So i created a `EventListener` called `TokenSetter`

**Here is the code**

```
class TokenSetter
{
protected $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $user = $args->getEntity();

    if ($user instanceof Account) {
        $clientManager = $this->container->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default');
        $client = $clientManager->createClient();
        $client->setRedirectUris(array('http://127.0.0.1:8000'));
        $client->setAllowedGrantTypes(array('password', 'refresh_token'));
        $clientManager->updateClient($client);

        $grantRequest = new Request(array(
            'client_id'  => $client->getPublicId(),
            'client_secret' => $client->getSecret(),
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            'password' => $user->getPlainPassword()
        ));

        $tokenResponse = $this->container->get('fos_oauth_server.server')->grantAccessToken($grantRequest);

        $token = $tokenResponse->getContent();
    }
}
}
```

The issue is that the `$user->getPlainPassword()` returns a empty value. This results in a "invalid_request" after creation.

Is there a way to get the plain password or generate the token a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

There are two ways to solve this.

First method is to change `password` to `client_credentials`. This way you do not need to send a username and password when generating a access token. The down side is that the value of the `user_id` will be set to `NULL`.

Second solution is to create a different listener. `(RegistrationListener)`

You need to edit the `UserEntity` and add a `TempPlainPass` getter and setter.
Basically what you need to do is, storing the plainpassword in the database `onRegistrationSuccess` and create a token with username and password on `onRegistrationCompleted`

***IMPORTANT!*** *Don't forget to delete the TempPlainPass after generating a token*

See the code below:

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
protected $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}


public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'onRegistrationCompleted',
    );
}

public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
    $user->setTempPlainPass($user->getPlainPassword());
    $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
}

public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $clientManager = $this->container->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default');
        $client = $clientManager->createClient();
        $client->setRedirectUris(array('http://127.0.0.1:8000'));
        $client->setAllowedGrantTypes(array('password', 'refresh_token'));
        $clientManager->updateClient($client);

        $grantRequest = new Request(array(
            'client_id'  => $client->getPublicId(),
            'client_secret' => $client->getSecret(),
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            'password' => $user->getTempPlainPass()
        ));

        $this->container->get('fos_oauth_server.server')->grantAccessToken($grantRequest);

        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
        $update = $em->getRepository(Account::class)->findOneById($user->getId());
        $update->setTempPlainPass('');
        $em->flush();
}
}
```